# I need to Set Promotion Buy A or B and Buy C Get Free D

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to Set Promotion Buy A or B and Buy C Get Free D

**Example:**

> Buy pen or pencil and buy ruler i will get free soap 1 piece

Please suggest me to set  cart price rule ?

Comment: Magento doesn't have these options in admin panel

Comment: Magento Version 2